# How can I make my controller call the correct view's component in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4

I defined a `Ext.grid.Panel` called `JobList` that has an Ext button with an `itemId` called `myButton`.  `JobList` has a controller.  In the controller I have the following code:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.JobList', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  refs: [
    {ref: 'jobList', selector: '#jobList'},
    {ref: 'myButton', selector: '#myButton'}
  ],
  init: function(){
    this.control({
      'jobList': {
        select: this.selectJob
      }
    });
  },
  selectJob: function(){
    this.getMyButton().enable();
  }
});
```

I then create two instances of `jobList` using `Ext.create` they have an id of `jobList1` and `jobList2`.  The problem is when I select a job in the list on `jobList2` it will enable the `myButton` on `jobList1` not `jobList2`.  How do I correctly enable the `myButton` on each instance of `jobList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid referencing by itemId, and use aliases instead:

```
// in App.view.JobList.js you should have
Ext.define('App.view.JobList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.job-list',
    // ...
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        name: 'myButton',
        text: 'My button',
    }]
});

// and the in the App.controller.JobList.js:
    // ...
    'job-list': {
        selectionchange: function(model, selected) {
            var button = model.view.up('job-list').down('button[name=myButton]');
            button.setDisabled(Ext.isEmpty(selected));
        }
     }
```

Check the example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tq1

Answer (score 1):

You're using global controller, so it catches events from all views that matching the query. Look at MVVM pattern in extjs5. Sencha did a great job, in MVVM each instance of view has their own instance of ViewController, so this situation will never happen. If you want to stick with MVC pattern, then you need to manually control this. Forget about refs, you can't use them if you have more than one instance of your view class. Get other components only by query from your current component. Something like:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.JobList', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
           'jobList': {
               select: this.selectJob
           }
        });
    },

    selectJob: function(selectionModel){
        //first of all you need to get a grid. We have only selectionModel in this event that linked somehow with our grid
        var grid = selectionModel.view.ownerCt; //or if you find more ellegant way to get a grid from selectionModel, use it
        var button = grid.down('#myButton');
        button.enable();
    }
});
```